# xpath to find preceding element

Tags: xpath

There is a structure like this:

```
<div "nothing unique there">
<img "repeating parameters">
<span>
    repeating text
</span>
<span>
    <span>
        <img class="unique name">
    </span>
    <span>
        <strong>Tools</strong>
    </span>
</span>
.
.
```

I need to find with XPath the `<img "repeating parameters">`
The only unique part in the code above is `<img class="unique name">`

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
//span/img[@class="unique name"]/preceding-sibling::img
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, if you want to select an `img`, then that should be the main part of your XPath. So, let's start with

```
//img
```

Now, let's add the conditions for that `img`. It seems that there's `span`following, so let's add that as a condition:

```
//img[following-sibling::span]
```

Now, that can't be any `span`. It needs to contain another `img`.

```
//img[following-sibling::span//img]
```

And that `img` again, is not just any `img`, but it has some special attributes. Let's add them as a condition to the inner `img`:

```
//img[following-sibling::span//img[@class="unique name"]]
```

There you go. IMHO a nice and understandable XPath.

---

Of course it would also be possible to go to the unique `img` first as you did.

```
//span/img[@class="unique name"]
```

Then, don't forget to step outwards:

```
//span/img[@class="unique name"]/../..
```

After that you can move to the preceding sibling:

```
//span/img[@class="unique name"]/../../preceding-sibling::img
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its a great explanation for myself as XPath beginner, totally makes sense and of course it works

Comment: @AlexanderSh: I'm glad it works. If one of the answers solved your problem, click the checkmark below the up/vote/down buttons. This will tell others that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `<img "repeating parameters">` is not a preceding  sibling of the `img` element you found, but rather of its grand-parent `<span>`. Use just `preceding::img` instead of `preceding-sibling::img`.